# Efficient map with case class as a key in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, case-class

A following C code uses enum and array as efficient "map" from enum to anything:

```
enum Color { ColorRed, ColorGreen, ColorBlue, ColorSize};


void f() {
  int x[ColorSize];
  x[ColorRed]   = 12;
  x[ColorGreen] = 33;
  x[ColorBlue]  = 4;
  return x[ColorGreen];
}
```

Is this possible with Scala?
I.e. to have a "map" from case class to something, implemented as efficient array and not as tree or as hashmap. Yet I would like to be able to index only with a paricular type not with  Int.

Update: In short I would like to have Scala Array indexed by some kind of enum (case class or Enumeration).

Comment: I guess I'm confused by the terminology. You'd like an array, but one that is indexed by enum rather than int?

Comment: An array is indexed by integers, always. If it's indexed by objects then it's some kind of hash table.

Comment: @Synesso: You are right. I updated the question.

Comment: @Synesso my comment was directed at @Łukasz Lew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small enumerations you can "simulate" the C behavior:

```
abstract sealed class Color(val index: Int)

object Color {
  implicit def col2int(color:Color) = color.index
}

case object ColorRed extends Color(0)
case object ColorGreen extends Color(1)
case object ColorBlue extends Color(2)

...

import Color._
val array = Array(1,2,3)
array(ColorRed) = 12
```

However, I doubt this would be considered good style, especially because it's unsafe. Using a map is a better approach, or you could wrap an array in a specialized data structure which deals with Color indizes:

```
class ColorArray[T:ClassManifest] {
  val array = new Array[T] (3)
  def apply(color: Color) = array(color.index)
  def update(color: Color, value: T) = array(color.index) = value
}

...

val cArray = new ColorArray[Int]()
cArray(ColorRed) = 12
println(cArray(ColorRed))
```

Comment: Note that you can write `abstract class Color` and `case object ColorX` here. Also, your array access return value does not match its declaration.

Comment: Corrected the Color definitions as suggested. I don't quite get your second remark.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Is there a way to find out how many cases of `Color` exist at runtime? Then you would have to hardcode the array size. You could do it with Java's enums.

Comment: For the second solution, why not include an implicit conversion to a regular array (or `Seq` or whatever) to get all the nice methods? For completeness, `object ColorArray` should be implemented, too.

Comment: The second solution works for both with case object and Scala Enumeration keys, in the second case you can automatically get the array length. Of course you can add implicit conversions, but array is not private, so you could simply call cArray.array and *have* all nice methods. It really depends on what you want to achieve. You have a lot of possibilities depending on your needs, with more or less convenience, more or less type safety and more or less performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
object Color extends Enumeration{
  val ColorRed, ColorGreen, ColorBlue = Value
}

import Color._
def f:Map[Color.Value,Int] = 
  Map(ColorRed -> 12 , ColorGreen -> 33, ColorBlue -> 4)
```

Comment: Is this as efficient as an array lookup?

Comment: The default Map implementation is a hash map, which provides pretty fast lookups.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full C performance you could do this:

```
trait CEnum {
private var size = 0;
def value = { size += 1; size-1 }
}

object Color extends CEnum {
  val colorRed = value 
  val colorGreen = value 
  val colorBlue = value 
  val colorSize = 3
}

import Color._

def f() = {
  val x = Array[Int](colorSize)
  x(colorRed) = 12
  x(colorGreen) = 33
  x(colorBlue) = 4
  x(colorGreen)
}
```

It's equally unsafe as the method in C & just as performant. It is however very unsafe.